# Как вывести в консоль объект с введенными данными?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook

Есть такие компоненты:

**App**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Header from '../src/components/Header'
import Users from '../src/components/Users'
import AddUser from './components/AddUser'

function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      firstname: 'Greg',
      secondname: 'Krissel',
      bio:'Spinner of Love',
      age: 58,
      isHappy: true
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      firstname: 'Brayn',
      secondname: 'Holland',
      bio:'Spinner of Hate',
      age: 57,
      isHappy: false
    }
  ])
  return(
    <div className="name">
      <Header title='List of users' />
      <main>
        <Users users={users}/>
      </main>
      <aside>
        <AddUser onAdd={addUser}/>
      </aside>
    </div>
  )
}

const addUser = user => {
  console.log(user)
}

export default App
```

И компонент **AddUser**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

function AddUser(props) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(
    {
      firstname: '',
      secondname: '',
      biografy: '',
      age: 1,
      isHappy: false
    }
  )

  return(
    <form>
      <input placeholder="Name" onChange={e => setState({ firstname: e.target.value })}/>
      <input placeholder="Secondname" onChange={e => setState({ secondname: e.target.value })}/>
      <input placeholder="Age" onChange={e => setState({ age: e.target.value })}/>
      <textarea placeholder="Bio" onChange={e => setState({ biografy: e.target.value })}></textarea>
      <label htmlFor="isHappy">Are you happy?</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="isHappy" onChange={e => setState({ isHappy: e.target.checked })}/>
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => props.onAdd(
          {
            firstname: state.firstname,
            secondname: state.secondname,
            age: state.age,
            biografy: state.biografy,
            isHappy: state.isHappy
          }
        )}>Add</button>
    </form>
  )
}

export default AddUser
```

Проблема возникает в том, что когда ввожу в inputы имя, фамилию и т.д. и нажимай на button, то в консоли появляется объект, но с одним заполненным свойством, а не со всеми!

Comment: Так у вас каждый инпут полностью перетирает значения предыдущего импута

Answer (score 1):

> Проблема возникает в том, что когда ввожу в inputы имя, фамилию и т.д. и нажимай на button, то в консоли появляется объект, но с одним заполненным свойством, а не со всеми!

Ты не верно меняешь стейты... Как в форме, так и у списка.

Предложу такой вариант.

```js
//
function AddUser(props) {
    const [state, setState] = React.useState(
        {
            firstname: '',
            secondname: '',
            biografy: '',
            age: 1,
            isHappy: false
        }
    );
    const setVal = name => e => setState(old => ({...old, [name]: e.target.value}))
    return(
        <form>
            <input placeholder="Name" onChange={setVal('firstname')}/>
            <input placeholder="Secondname" onChange={setVal('secondname')}/>
            <button type="button" onClick={() => props.onAdd(old =>
              [...old, {
                 id: new Date(),
                 firstname: state.firstname,
                 secondname: state.secondname,
                }
              ])}>Add</button>
        </form>
    );
}

//
function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = React.useState([
      {
          id: 1,
          firstname: 'Greg',
          secondname: 'Krissel',
          bio:'Spinner of Love',
          age: 58,
          isHappy: true
      },
      {
          id: 2,
          firstname: 'Brayn',
          secondname: 'Holland',
          bio:'Spinner of Hate',
          age: 57,
          isHappy: false
      }
  ]);
  return(
    <div>
      <main>
        <Users users={users}/>
      </main>
      <aside>
        <AddUser onAdd={setUsers} />
      </aside>
    </div>
  );
}
//
function Users({users}) {
  return <ul>
    {users.map(o => <li key={o.id}>{o.firstname} {o.secondname}</li>)}
  </ul>
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domContainer);
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="like_button_container"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное)